# Did Maul correctly state this character's secret identity? And if so, how did he know it?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In Star Wars Rebels,

> Darth Maul says that **Kanan Jarrus is really Caleb Dume** in S03E02.

Hera doesn’t dispute this.

**What does Maul base this on? Is there any proof that this is true?**

Answer (score 18):

This is confirmed in the canon novel *A New Dawn*:

> Kanan knew he was anything but lucky. For Kanan Jarrus was Caleb Dume,
> the Jedi who never was.
>
> <sub>*A New Dawn*</sub>

Various other sources for the same information, though none nearly so straightforward, can be found in the references to [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kanan_Jarrus) article.

As to how Maul knew his identity? Well, to judge from his hand motions, he was obviously doing some sort of

> Sith mind-reading, rather like what Kylo Ren has been seen to do. He presumably knows Kanan’s name because Hera Syndulla knows.

Comment: Well that seems pretty damn convincing

Comment: @Valorum - Yeah, this must be my shortest answer. I’d better see if I can find a way to expand it.

Comment: An animated gif is always good for a laugh.

Comment: Either that or go the other way. Remove everything but "*Kanan Jarrus was Caleb Dume*" from the quote.

Comment: Also confirmed in the Kanan comic, which is partially about... well, Kanan before he's Kanan.

Comment: @Adamant - I've found another source that is equally (if not more) succinct.

Comment: An animated gif from a novel? I'd like to see that!

Comment: Also Vader reads Luke's mind in Return of the Jedi.

Comment: @MarkRogers - yes, that's how he found out about his... sister. If HE would not turn, then perhaps SHE would....

Answer (score 6):

Per the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) factbook

> ***2 names:***
>   Kanan Jarrus's real name is "Caleb Dume"

Comment: And Maul purchased it at a newspaper stand the other day

Comment: @Yakk - Plus Amazon will deliver.

Comment: @Valorum Do you think Maul has prime? Could have been an employee perk. I wonder what other fringe benefits the empire offered...